# Reduced adverb clauses

Tags: grammar

I want to reduce the adverb clause in the this sentences:
"After he had been promoted, he became more interested in his job".

Which of the following sentences, if any, are wrong?

1. After promoted, he became more interested in his job.
2. After being promoted, he became more interested in his job.
3. Being promoted, he became more interested in his job.
4. Having been promoted, he became more interested in his job.

I'm especially wondering about the last one.

Comment: "having" implies a causal relationship, "after" a temporal one.

Answer (score -1):

So long AFTER is retained it's an adverb phrase, if not a participle phrase or a perfect participle phrase which, to be precise, is an adjective phrase from the point of functionality.

So (1) and (2) are adverb phrases and (3) and (4) are adjective phrases. We use perfect participle when one action has clear precedence over the other action and depends mostly on the speaker's or writer's intent.

All the phrases are grammatically correct.

Comment: I downvoted this answer as 1. is clearly incorrect, unless "promoted" means "advertised/publicised", which, from the context it does not appear to do. -- 2, 3 and 4 are free modifiers and act adverbially on the main clause.

Comment: I beg to differ, sir. Promoted in sl no (1) carries its normal sense of raised and advanced. But for the adverb, After, all the verbals are adjectives. "After" infuses time aspect and relates to the verb "become" in the main clause.

Comment: @Greybeard The first sentence is ungrammatical in *most*  — but not quite all — versions of English. The only prominent exception I can think of is in the so-called "needs washed" dialects, where "after **promoted"** there would mean "after **promoting"** or "after ***being* promoted"** to all the rest of us, who find it forever weird. Western Pennsylvania is (in:)famous for this construction, and natives use it frequently. But it also occurs in a line stretching west from there in a narrow band all the way till Iowa. Not to mention in parts of Scotland, whence it perhaps originated.

Comment: @tchrist I'm new to this site, and hope not to break any rules. How about this sentence: "When he was asked if he would support the president, he reluctantly said yes"; can I say: "when asked if he would support the president, he reluctantly said yes"?

Comment: @Amir That one's ok because it's standard "whiz" deletion of a tensed *be*.

Comment: A full adverbial clause can be reduced to a non finite clause by the deletion of the subject and whatever form of be it contains. This means that reduced adverbial clauses consist of a subordinating conjunction and can be followed by a phrase which can be :noun phrase, adjective phrase, prepositional phrase, -ing participle (if active voice) and -ed participle if passive voice. So the time sequence denominator 'after' with -ed participial (promoted) is a perfect adverb phrase and leaves no room of ambiguity and totally desirable.